# System.FormatException not able to find recognizable digits

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am getting the this error when I try to convert a hex string to byte array using the below code. Please help.

```
protected static byte[] HexStringToByte(string hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesCount = (hexString.Length) / 2;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesCount];
            for (int x = 0; x < bytesCount; ++x)
            {
                bytes[x] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: With what input? And why do you have a try/catch if you're just throwing? (Get rid of it - it's just noise.) Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: What is the input?It should work

Comment: Are you sure it is HEX (`W` is not in [0-9A-F] range)? Maybe you are looking for Base64?

Comment: You also have an O (oh) in there too...

Comment: I don't know much about the format of Hex string. I just wanted to convert this string into bytes so that size reduce to 16 and I can encrypt a string

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Can you suggest the format or range for Base64 string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HexaDecimal value

> 0ADB4DA38093W3350E49B0BA90O04A6C

which you have shared in your comment is invalid.

So the problem is in the code from where you are getting this HexaDecimal value.